cloud firestore rules for a CRUD app that uses firestore SDK to communicate to DB
I have a CRUD app which is a telegram bot written in express axios. I'm using firestore SDK and firebase npm package which seems like the preferred way to use my cloud firestore DB
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

let app;
let firestoreDb;

const initializeFirebaseApp = () => {
  try {
    app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firestoreDb = getFirestore();
    return app;
  } catch (error) {
    errorHandler(error, "firebase-initializeFirebaseApp");
  }
};

i have the setup done and its working fine without any rules
i read rule doc on official firestore cloud, and it was mostly about about how to write conditions, i couldnt find a straight forward documentation or guide about my problem.
I want my app to have full write/read access to my database how can i set rules for that?

I'm not clear - are you writing code for a web application running in a browser, or a backend application running nodejs?

@DougStevenson im writing a telegram bot

So, the JavaScript code you're writing to access Firestore - is it going to run in the browser or somewhere else on a backend?  I've never written a telegram bot or know anything about how that works, but it matters a lot where the code runs.

Seems to run on a server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430787/where-should-i-upload-my-telegram-bots-code-to-run and more from https://www.google.com/search?q=where+does+the+code+of+a+telegram+bot+run%3F

@DougStevenson its a backend app written in nodejs, it receives http requests from telegram api and sends responds back, for now im locally running it using nodejs and hosting it using Ngrok, i hope i understand your question right cause this is my first backend project

Since your code is going to run on a backend, you should not use the Firebase web client SDK as your code shows right now.  Instead, use the Firebase Admin SDK, which is meant for running code on backends.
Security rules are meant to control access coming directly from web and mobile clients where the end user is typically authenticated using Firebase Authentication.  This doesn't apply to your situation since your access will come from a backend.
When you use Firebase Admin, you will initialize it using a service account (and not the config object you show now), which you can get from your Firebase project.  There will be no need at all for security rules, since all access to Firebase will happen securely from your backend.  In fact, access this way will completely bypass any security rules that you happen to define.
Another option for nodejs is to use the GCP SDK for Firestore.  The Firebase Admin SDK just wraps this SDK, so it is functionally the same.  You might prefer to use this instead of Firebase SDKs since you don't actually need any of what Firebase adds to Firestore for web and mobile clients.
